# counting up with characters based on index

Tags: algorithm, go

My current code:

```
var basicChars = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
func GetFromIndex(index int) string {
    length := len(basicChars)

    size := 0 // size is the amount of characters in the final string
    for {
        if float64(index) > math.Pow(float64(length), float64(size))-2 {
            size++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    str := make([]rune, size)

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        str[i] = basicChars[index%length]
    }

    return string(str)
}
```

I am trying to count up with letters instead of numbers.

I know I can use for loops but there is no good way of saving state or going up indefinitely

Comment: declaring a variable and a function doesn't really count as "code". did you actually try to implement this function? To me it is not clear what you want to achieve here. "letters should count up"? "add another row" (another implies one was already added but when/where)? "limit was exceeded" (which limit)?

Comment: @Mihai I have tried implementing but it didn't work. Basically I need a function that counts up but with letters instead of numbers.

Comment: show what you tried and then maybe it becomes clear what you are trying to achieve. I seriously have no idea what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have added my attempt. I believe this partially works. It should get the correct string length but all the strings are repeating. eg. "bbb" instead of "aab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your description GetFromIndex(122) should return a8, not bb

either I didn't get the correct scenario or we are missing informations

-eddit-

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it

- the first character will moove every time
- the 2nd -> 3 times
- the 3rd -> 9 times ...

I substract the useless cycles

- the 2nd -> each 3 * len(array)
- the 3rd -> each 9 * len(array)

and get their position in the array

```
func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    for i:=0; i<=30; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s i:{%d} \n",GetFromIndexBis(i),i)
    }

}
func GetFromIndex(index int) string {
    var basicChars = []rune("abc")
    len := len(basicChars)
    pow := 1
    sumPow := 0
    res :=""    
    
    // the first is a simple modulo
    res += string(basicChars[index%len])
    
    for {
        
        pow = pow * len
        // is the index big enought ?
        if index < pow+sumPow{
            break
        }

        // remove the first cycles where nothing pushed the wheels
        start := index - sumPow

        // number of cycle we need to make a full turn
        fullCycles := pow * len

        if start>=fullCycles {
            nbrOfUselessCycles := start / fullCycles
            start = start - fullCycles * nbrOfUselessCycles
        }

        index := (start / pow) -1

        // it's the last one
        if (index == -1) {
            res += string(basicChars[len-1])    
        }else {
            res += string(basicChars[index])
        }
        
        sumPow += pow
    }
    
    return res
}
```

Comment: yea i probably got the math wrong

Comment: sorry but your new example is also wrong, it's a
b
c
--
aa
ab
ac
--
ba
bb
bc
--
ca
cb
cc
--
aab
aac

Comment: yea ik, i wasnt going to type 400 lines

Comment: it was not about the number of examples, but the errors in the informations that lead of us misunderstanding